# Unable to pass schema name in execute immediate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to pass as a parameter the schema name into an execute immediate command.

```
DECLARE
  sql_stmt  VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   sql_stmt := 'DROP INDEX :owner.".MY_INDEX"';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt using  &owner_name ;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
```

The above raises following oracle error:
***ORA-06550: line 5, column 38:
PLS-00201: identifier 'USER_X' must be declared***

I have tried also tried to concatenate the sql_stmt without success though. I receive the exact same error as above:

```
DECLARE
  sql_stmt  VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   sql_stmt := 'DROP INDEX ' || &owner. || '".MY_INDEX";';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt ;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
```

Any suggestions to pass the username as a variable in the execute statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following works. I was missing a dot '.':

```
DECLARE
  sql_stmt  VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   sql_stmt := 'DROP INDEX &owner_name.."MY_INDEX"';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be assigning values through variables not directly to the execute immediate. If you use variables then this block can be reused for other purposes too. Always try to make blocks in such a way it can be reused. Hope below snippet helps.

```
SET define ON;
DECLARE
  sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(200);
  lv_chema_nm VARCHAR2(100):='&Enter_schema_name';
  lv_obj_type VARCHAR2(100):='&Enter_obj_type';
  lv_obj_name VARCHAR2(100):='&Enter_obj_name';
BEGIN
  sql_stmt := 'DROP '||lv_obj_type ||' '|| lv_chema_nm||'.'||lv_obj_name;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt ;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
    RAISE;
  END IF;
END;
```